# Vue.js error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, search, filter, axios

Im building an app to consume a json and list it with a search filter input and other stuffs

I've already tried to create the function but didnt work

```
{
    produtoFiltrado:function()
    {
         var self=this;
       return this.produtos.filter(function(cust){
         return cust.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase())>=0;
         });
    }
}
```

Its showing this error:  Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Here is the codesandbox url:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-7iev3?fontsize=14

Comment: Did produtos is an array? Did it depends on a Promise? Try test if this.produtos exists with an if before do `this.produtos.filter`. Also, check it value with `console.log(this.produtos);` because it is *undefined*

Comment: @MatheusValenza It were missing the [ ] of produtos array but now its ok... Actually now its showing another error:  Cannot read property 'search' of undefined. But i've already defined search

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed with the declaration of array

produtos: [ { all-stuffs-here } ]

The brackets were missing

But now its showing this error:

Cannot read property 'search' of undefined